# MongoDB should I put users in admin db or local db

Tags: mongodb

Is there any best practice in MongoDB as to where I should put my database users?

I've just set up a local MongoDB server and I've added users in the admin database and granted them access to "their" (by their I mean the only database the users have access to) database.

Do you think it would be better to just put the users in "their" database and not in the admin database?

Comment: A centralised admin db simplifies user management and connection management, but is less secure if you have any *admin roles used in operational queries.

Answer (score 7):

Regardless of the user's [authentication database](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-users/#user-authentication-database), Mongo always stores user information in `admin`.

> MongoDB stores all user information, including name, password, and the user's authentication database, in the `system.users` collection in the admin database.

See [centralized-user-data](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-users/#centralized-user-data) and [system-users-collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/system-users-collection/).

When you create a user and grant that user access to a single database (aka their authentication database) then that information can **only** be stored in the `admin` database.

So, it's not really a question of "best practice"; storing user details in `admin` is MongoDB's choice, as implemented by their [user management commands](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/#user-management-commands).

**Update** in response to this comment:

> Ok, so the users are always located in the admin db, but I may also add "duplicates" to the other dbs? Maybe the question should be whether there any advantage in adding users to the other "non admin" dbs?

If you intend to have a single user with access to multiple databases then create a single user with roles in each of those databases rather than creating that user multiple times i.e. once in each of those databases. For example:

```
use admin;
db.createUser({user:'userName', pwd:'passwordValue', roles:[
    {role:'readWrite', db:'DatabaseA'},
    {role:'readWrite', db:'DatabaseB'}
]});
```

Comment: I believe the question is about logical database, not physical storage. I.e. the `db` field in the `system.users` collections and `authenticationDatabase` option of the connection.  To elaborate `use their; db.createUser({user:'u', pwd:'u', roles:[{role:'readWrite', db:'their'}]}); use admin; db.createUser({user:'u', pwd:'u', roles:[{role:'readWrite', db:'their'}]});` will create 2 **different** users with identical name, password, and permissions. The only difference is the authentication database - the _id prefix and `db` field in system.users collection.

Comment: I initially suspected that that but this statement: _"by their I mean the only database the users have access to"_ suggested to me that the question was based on a misunderstanding of where the user data is located rather than it being a question about multiple users with the same name or users having acess to multiple databases.

Comment: Yeah, fair enough. The wording of the question is not ideal, but since you can create identical users with the only difference in authentication database, the obvious question is which one to use. It would be nice to give some recommendations in the answer.

Comment: Ok, so the users are always located in the admin db, but I may also add "duplicates" to the other dbs? Maybe the question should be whether there any advantage in adding users to the other "non admin" dbs? (Sorry for the wording I'm not a native English speaker)

Comment: No problem with your English :) it's just this area is somewhat ambiguous: the "authentication database" can be different to the database to which you assign access and regardless of the name of the "authentication database" or the name of the database to which you assign access all details are stored in `admin`. So, plenty of room for confusion there :)