# MongoDB. Use admin database to create users vs. other database

Tags: mongodb, authentication

I am starting to learn MongoDB.
I can create users connected to the admin database:

```
 use admin
 db.createUSer({
    user: "username",
    pwd: "password",
    roles: [{role:"readWrite", db:"dbaseName"}],
 } )
```

Or connected to `dabaseName`:

```
 use dbaseName
 db.createUSer({
    user: "username",
    pwd: "password",
    roles: [{role:"readWrite", db:"dbaseName"}],
 } )
```

What is the difference?

Comment: Here is some related info: [Mongodb authentication database best practice](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195155/mongodb-authentication-database-best-practice) _and_ [MongoDB should I put users in admin db or local db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49445201/mongodb-should-i-put-users-in-admin-db-or-local-db).

Comment: @prasad_ it is quite confusing. One of your links says doesn't matter because users are always created in the admin database.  The other link says the contrary.

Comment: In such a case, I think you can try what you feel is best for you. I have used admin database only, so far. I am leaning towards using admn database. Unless you have a compelling reason to do otherwise, and its your choice.